# What does 'wired'(line1) mean?

Tags: meaning

> Now, I don’t have to tell a crowd of Red Sox fans that we are **wired**
>   for tribalism. But beyond rooting for the home team, tribalism has a
>   much darker side. Instinctively and maybe even genetically, we divide
>   the world into ‘us’ and ‘them.’ So the burning question must be: How
>   do all of us together find the ‘we?’ How do we do that? There’s still
>   so much work to be done, and sometimes I feel the work hasn’t even
>   begun. And it’s not just anti-Semitism that’s surging --
>   Islamophobia’s on the rise, too. Because there’s no difference between
>   anyone who is discriminated against, whether it’s the Muslims, or the
>   Jews, or minorities on the border states, or the LGBT community -- it
>   is all big one hate.

- Steven Spielberg Speech | Harvard Commencement 2016

Answer (score 1):

It means that tribalism is present innately in the brain, a shortening of hardwired. As part of a larger context, wired separates innate tribalism (the *wired*) versus taught tribalism.

Comment: Well put. Spielberg is saying that in the classic question of 'nature or nurture*, tribalism comes from our built-in nature.